# Visual Studio Code Extension Variable

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know if it's possible to write an extension in Visual Studio code that can write the values in the variables window to a file after each step while in debug mode. So, a step would happen, the variable would get written to a file, another step would happen, and the next set of variables would be written. Is there anything like this out there? Can it even be done?

Here's what I have so far:
1) I created an extension in VS code, and will write my functionality in the following provided method:

```
function activate(context) {

let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', function () {

    // Display a message box to the user
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World!');

});
```

2) There are some variables offered here that could be relevant (such as debugger), but they throw errors when I use them.

To explain more clearly, what I would like to do is the following: create an extension in VS code that when used launches another instance of VS code (as does every extension), and within this new instance, load a user program, debug the program step by step, and write the variables at each step of the user program to a file. This main reason for even making the extension is the last step, as VS Code doesn't have any built in functionality to do anything like this that I know of. One issue is I am not sure the 'debugger' variable in the extension (or any variables) refer to the new instance, and if there is a way to do this.

If there is a better and smarter approach, I would love to hear it.

Thank you very much everyone in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! For sure it is possible but what did you try?

Comment: Updated initial post to cover information. Thank you for welcoming me.